# xpath relative path does not bring back any value

Tags: xpath, svg

there is that part of an SVG file

```
<g transform="translate(113.63-359.13)">
    <use fill="#f00" xlink:href="#D"/>
    <g transform="translate(72.59-8.504)">
        <use xlink:href="#E"/>
        <path fill="#f00" stroke="#000" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width=".24" d="m6.04 526.26h19.843v4.961h-19.843z"/>
        <use xlink:href="#F"/>
    </g>
    <text x="20.41" y="527.6" fill="#000" font-family="Arial" font-size="8">Out</text>
</g>
```

to find that particular g node with Text = Out it works to use

```
svg/g/text[text()="Out"]
```

but I don't get #f00 when using this relative path

```
/svg/g/text[text()="Out"]./use/@fill
```

can anyone enlighten me what the issue is and how I could find the fill value reltaive to "Out" ?

FYI I am trying to write an XSL to change the color for some objects in a svg file. If you have any thing additional to that topic it would be great

Thanks

Comment: `/svg/g/text[text()="Out"]./use/@fill` is not a relative path, it is an illegal XPath expression (the dot), you should receive have an error. Also, even after removing the dot, it is not a relative path, it is an absolute path, starting at the root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your XML does have a root element called `svg` above the current `g` element, the expression you are looking for is this....

```
/svg/g/text[text()="Out"]/../use/@fill
```

Or better still, do this...

```
/svg/g[text/text()="Out"]/use/@fill
```

Comment: Your assumtion is absolutly right and I can't believe I tried that...work fine thanks !

Comment: @user3732793 If Tim has answered your question, please [**accept his answer**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). That's the standard way to resolve an issue on Stackoverflow.

Comment: `/text()` can be dropped: `/svg/g[text="Out"]/use/@fill`